# Disqus not firing when button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, disqus

Does anyone have experience with Disqus?
I am adding buttons to the existing website and when button is pressed, it should fire disqus comments.

In the beginning, this is run

```
function insertdisqus(){
  var dsq = document.createElement('script'); 
  dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; 
  dsq.async = true;
  dsq.src = 'https://myforum.disqus.com/embed.js';
  $('head').append(dsq);
```

}

then,

```
var button = document.createElement("a");
  button.setAttribute("id", "diqus");
  button.innerHTML = "Discussion";
  button.addEventListener('click', loaddisqus);

function loaddisqus(e){
  parent_element = $(this).parent().parent();
  next_element = parent_element.next();
  subjectcode = next_element.attr('data-subjectcode');

  var disqus_identifier = subjectcode;
  var disqus_url = window.location.origin; 
  next_element.after('<div id="disqus_thread"></div>');
```

so, when the button is pressed, loaddisqus should execute, and it does. But it doesn't do anything further than creating the disqus_thread divs...
What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

first thing, you try to mix plain javascript and jquery (not a good idea)

perhaps you can try something like this:

```
var btn = $('<button>').html('Duscussion').on('click', btnClickListener);
$('body').append(btn);

var btnClickListener = function(event){
  var clickedElement = $(this); // get the clicked element
  clickedElement.html('new Text'); // do what you want (i.e. change the content of the clicked button)
}
```

second is, you try to use a link (a-tag) as an button. the problem is, a link allways tries to relocate your page to the href target. a button should be a button, not a link. if you need a link because of style or something you have to expend your listener function to something like this:

```
var linkButton = $('<a>').attr('href', '#').html('click here').on('click', linkButtonListener);
$('body').append(linkButton);

var linkButtonListener = function(event){
  event.stopPropagation(); // stops actions from all parent elements
  event.preventDefault(); // stops the default actions of the link
  var clickedButton = $(this); // get the clicked element
  clickedButton.html('allready clicked'); // do what you want (i.e. change the content of the link)
}
```

i hope that helps you to understand how the listeners with jquery works very simple.

last thing, you try to enable a script tag and hope the script runs after click on your button. but this does not work in javascript. all scripts will be loaded once. you can't execute it by adding a script tag after the document is ready. if you want this, you have to execute it by hand (perhaps with eval function), but it's not the fine way. There are some frameworks that can include scripts by action and make them executeable i think. i know it does not work and never used it.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I mean, as I was writing the code, I felt the same because I'm really new to javascript.... but I mean the point is that, I think I am doing something wrong with the rather Disqus endpoint, because even though code may be ugly and not in correct format, it still works and the script runs at the right time, as I checked and debugged. Just that Disqus should look for the div tag that is added and automatically load the comments on their end...